# Logic Apps: Using the "compose" action with an IF statement

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I am using a compose action in a logic app in which I need to use a logical function that if xx condition passes then it can take the output from one compose action say compose1 and if failed then it can use from compose2
I tried to use the "if" logical function but it keeps saying that the expression is wrong.
Ex what I have used ...

```
if(contains(outputs('Create_duplicateKey'),'SendVehicleOrder'),'outputs('Compose_Priority')','outputs('Compose_Category')')
```

I have also tried to directly use the outputs of compose1 and compose2 but it is still failing ...

```
if(contains(outputs('Create_duplicateKey'),'SendVehicleOrder'),'Id: @{items('Loop_through_all_alerts')?['ID']}','orderType: @{items('Loop_through_all_alerts')?['OrderType']}')
```

Is there anyway I can use these outputs in an expression

Comment: In your first statement, try removing the quotes around the `outputs` (i.e. do this ... `if(contains(outputs('Create_duplicateKey'),'SendVehicleOrder'),outputs('Compose_Priority'),outputs('Compose_Category'))`) ... it may very well not work though.  If so, it'd be useful if you provided some data that we can test with ourselves along with screenshots of your flow.  It's hard to work through without the added details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, like @Skin mentioned removing quotes will make it work.

```
if(contains(outputs('Create_duplicateKey'),'SendVehicleOrder'),outputs('Compose_Priority'),outputs('Compose_Category'))
```

Alternatively, you can use condition action to achieve your requirement.

[image]